# Is there an API to add markers to user created public/unlisted maps in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a map with a few markers and saved it at http://maps.google.com/.

Is there a way to edit the map with an API, like inserting and deleting markers from it?
Or, is there a way to add markers to the default preview at http://maps.google.com/ without saving it? (Possibly through adding parameters to the URL).

The problem raises due to contract between Google Maps and Israel's map provider, which doesn't allow Google to show Israel's streets through an API, and only through the interactive map at http://maps.google.com/.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Google Maps API, you can save markers in an database, so, you can inser, delete, update markers. When you load you web app where you are using the API you have to create an XML file with coordenates and info, then use a javascript to read XML file

Comment: Even though that's not exactly an answer to what I asked, it does have a nice idea to doing it, with XML files and importing. Thanks for input!